# Any classifier in `sklearn` that can handle each `M[i,j]` as an array/tuple/or distribution?

Tags: python, algorithm, machine-learning, scikit-learn, classification

I've been learning how to use machine-learning classifiers lately and got started thinking if there was anything in `sklearn` that could take in either an array or a distribution for each `i,j` cell as training data? **Does such a classification algorithm exist in `scikit-learn`?** If so, how is it used? If not, can someone provide some insight into any algorithms that are known to handle this type of data?

Somebody asked kind of a similar question: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/178109/linear-regression-problem-with-multi-dimensional-vectors-instead-of-scalar-value#comment443880_178109 but it was for Regression and it was also never answered.

I tried using just a `RandomForestClassifier` but it didn't like the array instead of the scalar. If it's more a Bayesian problem, I would be keen on using `PyMC3` but I don't even know what algorithms to look at to even start the process.

```
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier
# Create 2 Distinguishable Classes, 20 of each
# Where each column has a fixed size for the array (e.g. `attr_0`=3, `attr_1`=5, `attr_2`=2)
class_A = np.vstack([[np.random.normal(loc=0, scale=1,size=3),
                      np.random.normal(loc=5, scale=1,size=5),
                      np.random.normal(loc=10, scale=1,size=2)] for k in range(20)])

class_B = np.vstack([[np.random.normal(loc=15, scale=1,size=3),
                      np.random.normal(loc=20, scale=1,size=5),
                      np.random.normal(loc=30, scale=1,size=2)] for k in range(20)])

# Merge them
Ar_data = np.concatenate([class_A,class_B], axis=0)
X = pd.DataFrame(Ar_data, columns=["attr_0","attr_1","attr_2"])

# Create target vector
y = np.array(20*[0] + 20*[1])

# Test data
X_test = [np.random.normal(loc=0, scale=1,size=3),
          np.random.normal(loc=5, scale=1,size=5),
          np.random.normal(loc=10, scale=1,size=2)]
X_test
# [array([-0.15510844,  0.04567395, -0.66192602]),
#  array([ 4.5412568 ,  4.32526163,  4.56558114,  5.48178697,  5.2559264 ]),
#  array([  9.17293292,  10.19746434])]
```

[image]

I tried fitting a `RandomForestClassifier` but it didn't work :(

```
Mod_rf = RandomForestClassifier()
Mod_rf.fit(X,y)
# ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.
```

Comment: Classical machine learning takes a set of feature vectors as input. The conventional way here is to extract meaningful features from your arrays (maybe summary statistics such as mean, median, spread, ...) and use them as features to describe your data vectors.

Comment: The model using distributions instead of scalars is insanely hard and may be tackled by **stochastic programming** (which is still kind of a young discipline). But there is no support for this in scikit-learn.